# PHP preg_match mysql time datatype in the format xxx:xx:xx

Tags: php, validation, time, preg-match

Looking for the correct preg_match (or other solution) to validate a string to go in mysql time datatype.
The format is xxx:xx:xx and between ranges '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'

Also in mind that "7:53:48", "23:59", "145:19:59", and "-16:24:33" are all **valid inputs**  but "930:00:00", 128:61:61" and "63:59" are all **invalid.**

I've got this far from a normal time preg_match

```
preg_match("/([0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $time)
```

But this only validates the minutes and seconds properly. Any ideas !?

Also note that I understand that time mysql datatype also accepts values without the colons, but that's been handled separately already ;)

**EDIT**

I'm really sorry guys, missunderstood mysql doc. 70:59 is actually valid input, it will be translated to 70:59:00

Comment: Why is `23:59` valid but `63:59` invalid? They are both in the acceptable range.

Comment: @Tomalak It is valid indeed, shame on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<![0-9:])-?([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-7][0-9][0-9]|8[0-2][0-9]|83[0-8]):([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?(?![0-9:])
```

Explanation:

```
(?<!                  # look-behind: makes sure we are at the start of a time
  [0-9:]              #   ...not preceded by a digit or a colon
)                     # end look-behind
-?                    # a minus, optional
(                     # group 1 (hours)
   [0-9]              #   single-digit 0-9
   |                  #   or
   [0-9][0-9]         #   double-digit 00-99
   |                  #   or
   [1-7][0-9][0-9]    #   triple-digit 100-799
   |                  #   or
   8[0-2][0-9]        #   triple-digit 800-829
   |                  #   or
   83[0-8]            #   triple-digit 830-838
)                     # end group 1
:                     # :
(                     # group 2 (minutes)
   [0-5][0-9]         #   00-59
)                     # end group 2
(?:                   # non-capturing group
  :                   #   :
  (                   #   group 3 (seconds)
    [0-5][0-9]        #     00-59
  )                   #   end group 3
)?                    # end group, make optional
(?!                   # look-ahead: makes sure we are at the end of a time
  [0-9:]              #   ...not followed by a digit or a colon
)                     # end look-ahead
```

This actually matches time strings in a larger text, instead of just validating them.

Comment: 70:59 comes out as valid, and it shouldn't

Comment: @Eduardo So `70:59` is somehow magically not in the range `-838:59:59` to `838:59:59`?

Comment: easy bro. Miss-understood the documentation. It is valid indeed. I've Edited the question and will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Bah. I'd say mine's tidier. :)

Comment: @Eduardo I am easy, no worries.

Comment: @MichaelRushton +1 your answer. Yours tidier, but Tomalak gave teh answer correctly in first and explained it aswell ;)

Comment: @MichaelRushton Sorry, your's is not wrong, my bad. +1 to you. As long as the time string is the only input (i.e. pure validation, not searching in a larger text), your's is fine.

Comment: Upvoted just for the explanation which allowed me to customize for my use :)

Comment: @Costa Thanks for the feedback. I've noted and fixed a bug (compare the version history) - Check you did not accidentally copy it!

Answer (score 2):

```
/^-?([0-7]?[0-9]{1,2}|8([0-2][0-9]|3[0-8]))(:[0-5][0-9]){1,2}$/D
```

Comment: Done thanks a lot ;) Just need to wait 5 min to accept the answer

Comment: Simplified the minute/second part as well.

Comment: It won't accept single-digit or two-digit hour parts, will it?

Comment: The default is `00:00:00`. I don't think it will accept single digit, which I've accounted for in my regex (I updated it to reflect this a minute after I first posted it with single-digit allowance).

Comment: Ignore above. Misunderstood you. Changed to allow single-digit.